# Tried to open a new tab in chrome browser but it is not opening a new tab

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"t");
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
    driver.get("http://www.qaautomated.com");
```

I tried using Key.chord but it is not opening a new tab

Comment: What if you _don't_ use `Key.chord`? (as shown on that site)

Comment: Yes, I tried without using Key.chord also but it is not working. I am using chrome driver only

Comment: It should work with just Keys.CONTROL + "t"

Comment: Hi Bill, i tried this but it is not opening new tab

Answer (score 1):

This seem to be `chromedriver` issue. You can use below code instead to open new tab:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.open()");
```

If you want to open `URL` in new tab, then just pass it as argument as:

```
jse.executeScript("window.open('http://www.qaautomated.com')");
```

Comment: This code helps to open a new tab but i need a solution how to make user of keyboard short cuts in selenium

Comment: Then use `Firefox` instead of `Chrome`

Comment: I tried using Actions class in firefox driver but it is not working, Below is my code snippet but it is also failing.
Actions keyAction = new Actions(driver);     
keyAction.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("t").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();

Comment: `Actions()` not supported by `Firefox` for now